# How can I get a list of members who are in one voice channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

What did I wrong that I get: "<property object at 0x000001B73702C130>" this in the console?
I want an list of members...
What does "<property object at 0x000001B73702C130>" mean?
Can someone help me?

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Uhf.png)

```
@client.command() async def mute(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(770290180887805972)
    voice_members = discord.VoiceChannel.members
    print(f'{voice_members}')
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: I have added a picture of my code @Shenanigator

Comment: Please add your code in code brackets(``` `code here` ```) not in image.

Comment: Okay i edited the message @Nurqm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're calling the class, not the `channel` object that you get from `channel = client.get_channel(id)`. You have to do `voice_members = channel.members` instead of `voice_members = discord.VoiceChannel.members`.

Comment: Okay cool thanks,
But how can I do that voice_members = the UserID?

Comment: I couldn't understand your question, can you explain it more? If it's long and another question, you can ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

`VoiceChannel` looks to be the class definition, not an instance of the class.  If you had an instance of the class the property could return a value, but because you don't, it just returns the property method.